# React/TypeScript: Consuming context via HOC

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement the example [Consuming Context with a HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consuming-context-with-a-hoc) from the React documentation (React 16.3) in TypeScript (2.8) and failing miserably. For reference, the code from React's manual:

```
const ThemeContext = React.createContext('light');

// This function takes a component...
export function withTheme(Component) {
  // ...and returns another component...
  return function ThemedComponent(props) {
    // ... and renders the wrapped component with the context theme!
    // Notice that we pass through any additional props as well
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {theme => <Component {...props} theme={theme} />}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    );
  };
}
```

The best I could come up with:

```
export interface ThemeAwareProps {
  theme: string;
}

const ThemeContext = React.createContext('light');

export function withTheme<P extends ThemeAwareProps, S>(Component: new() => React.Component<P, S>) {
  return function ThemedComponent(props: P) {
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {theme => <Component {...props} theme={theme} />}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    );
  };
}

class App extends React.Component {

  public render() {
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={'dark'}>
        <ThemedButton/>
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

ThemedButton.tsx:

```
interface ThemedButtonProps extends ThemeAwareProps {
}

interface ThemedButtonState{
}

class ThemedButton extends React.Component<ThemedButtonProps, ThemedButtonState> {

  constructor(props: ThemedButtonProps) {
    super(props);
  }


  public render() {
    return (
      <button className={this.props.theme}/>
    )
  }
}

export default withTheme(ThemedButton);
```

The problem is the last line (`export default withTheme(ThemedButton)`). The TypeScript compiler complains that

> Argument of type `typeof ThemedButton` is not assignable to parameter of type `new () => Component<ThemedButtonProps, ThemedButtonState, any>`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You got it right for the most part, just with a few missing pieces:

1. For `Component`, use `React.ComponentType<Props>`, which correctly accepts class components and functional components. I figure using `new () => ...` alone doesn't work here because the signatures didn't fully match up.
2. To exclude the props from `ThemedButton` while using it, you'll have to use some magical-looking syntax:

```ts
function ThemedComponent(props: Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, keyof ThemeAwareProps>>)
```

Here's what this does:

- `Exclude<keyof P, keyof ThemeAwareProps>` means "get the keys of `P`, then take away the keys that are in `ThemeAwareProps`"
- `Pick<P, ...>` then says, "from `P`, return an object type with only these properties"

Combining these gives us a component that accepts all the props that `ThemedButton` does, minus the `theme` prop, so that we can do `<ThemedButton />` without errors.

Here's the full HOC:

```
function withTheme<P extends ThemeAwareProps>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) {
  return function ThemedComponent(props: Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, keyof ThemeAwareProps>>) {
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {(theme) => <Component {...props} theme={theme} />}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
}
```

[And finally, a good blog post on the subject, from which I gleamed most of this information from.](https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript-42278f7590fb) It also includes a way to shorten the `Pick<...>` stuff with an `Omit` type, if you prefer.

---

EDIT: [The behavior of rest/spread has changed in 3.2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/11/29/announcing-typescript-3-2/#object-spread-on-generic-types), and [this bug came up as an unfortunate side effect](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28938), causing the type of `props` to get erased when merged with other props. [A currently working workaround is to cast `props` as `P`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53982922/1332403):

```
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {(theme) => <Component {...props as P} theme={theme} />}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    )
```

Comment: Your proposed solution seemingly no longer works. Please refer to my newest question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53982774/796036

Comment: After some reproduction and a bit of digging, found that it's a bug in TS. [Here's the issue thread.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28938) The solution you've found seems to be the only workaround at the moment. I'll update my answer. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @Jeff That sounds more like a problem with the imports, exports, or with the babel/TS config

Comment: @kingdaro Yup, nvm. CRA was resolving circular dependencies, webpack was not. Deleting my previous comment. Thanks