# HoC for context consumer causing type error with child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I am having an issue wherein I attempt to write a HoC in order to wrap components that should have access to a particular context via newly injected props.

There is a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/thehappybug/88342c122cfb1df9f14c9a10fb4926e4) related to a tutorial which basically contains the following snippet:

```
export function withAppContext<
    P extends { appContext?: AppContextInterface },
    R = Omit<P, 'appContext'>
>(
    Component: React.ComponentClass<P> | React.StatelessComponent<P>
): React.SFC<R> {
    return function BoundComponent(props: R) {
        return (
            <AppContextConsumer>
                {value => <Component {...props} appContext={value} />}
            </AppContextConsumer>
        );
    };
}
```

Similarly there is [another snippet here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50613946/796036) which looks as follows:

```
function withTheme<P extends ThemeAwareProps>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) {
    return function ThemedComponent(props: Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, keyof ThemeAwareProps>>) {
        return (
            <ThemeContext.Consumer>
                {(theme) => <Component {...props} theme={theme} />}
            </ThemeContext.Consumer>
        )
    }
}
```

They are pretty much the same and apparently worked once, however this is no longer the case. Using both variants the child component `Component` in the render prop of the consume is underlined with the following error message:

```
Type '{ exploreContext: IExploreContextStore; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & P & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
    Property 'exploreContext' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & P & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

My sample code where is issue occurs is as folows:

```
type WithExploreContext = { exploreContext?: IExploreContextStore };

export function withExploreContext<P extends WithExploreContext>(ChildComponent: ComponentType<P>) {
    return function WrappedComponent(
        props: Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, keyof WithExploreContext>>
    ) {
        return <Consumer>{(value) => <ChildComponent {...props} exploreContext={value} />}</Consumer>;
    };
}
```

I pretty much have no clue what's the issue with these snippets and why they no longer work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spreading the `props` to the child component alone wasn't sufficient. It started working right after casting it to `P` using `{...props as P}`.

Starting with 3.2 the [behaviour of the spread operator for generics has changed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/11/29/announcing-typescript-3-2/#object-spread-on-generic-types). Apparently the type of `props` gets erased as a negative side effect, but you can work around that by casting it back to `P` using `{...props as P}` when spreading back into the wrapped component.